# Angle between tangents and angle subtended by radii are supplementary

Tags: geometry, circles

> Using the result that the length of the tangents draw from an external point to a circle are equal, prove that the angle between the two tangents drawn from an external point to a circle is supplementary to the angle subtended by the line segment joining the points of contact at the center.

[image: Figure for question]

I can easily prove this by the following:

> $\angle OQP = \angle ORP =  90^{\circ}$
>
> So in quadrilateral $OQPR$ $ \angle QPR + \angle QOR = 180^{\circ}$ and therefore these angles are supplementary.

But I have not used what is said in the question. How should I do it?

Comment: Please don't write all in caps, it looks very impolite and untidy.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** Try to use congruence. If you can prove that the two triangles are congruent then it is a kite. Now, you can prove it easily.

Answer (score 0):

Let us consider a circle centered at point $O$. Let $P$ be an external point from which two tangents $PA$ and $PB$ are drawn to the circle which are touching the circle at point $A$ and $B$ respectively and $AB$ is the line segment, joining point of contacts $A$ and $B$ together such that it subtends $\angle AOB$ at center $O$ of the circle.

It can be observed that

$OA$ (radius) $\perp$ $PA$ (tangent)

Therefore, $\angle OAP = 90^\circ$

Similarly, $OB$ (radius) $\perp$ $PB$ (tangent)

$\angle OBP = 90^\circ$

In quadrilateral $OAPB$,

Sum of all interior angles $= 360^\circ$

$\angle OAP +\angle APB+\angle PBO +\angle BOA = 360^\circ$

$90^\circ + \angle APB + 90^\circ + \angle BOA = 360^\circ$

$\angle APB + \angle BOA = 180^\circ$

Hence, it can be observed that the angle between the two tangents drawn from an external point to a circle is supplementary to the angle subtended by the line-segment joining the points of contact at the center.

Answer (score -2):

To prove:  $BPA + BOA = 180^\circ$

Solution: In quadrilateral $AOBP$, $PBO = 90^\circ$ (as the angle between the radius and the tangent to the circle is $90^\circ$). Similarly, $PAO = 90^\circ$. $PAO + PBO + BOA + BPA = 360^\circ$ (the sum of the angles of a quadrilateral), therefore $90^\circ + 90^\circ + BOA + BPA = 360^\circ$, so (since we have proved that $PAO = 90^\circ$ and $PBO = 90^\circ$) $BOA + BPA = 360^\circ - 180^\circ = 180^\circ$.

Comment: This is very hard to read.  Your answer would be much better if you wrote a few complete sentences and formatted it nicely with MathJax/Latex.  I suggest you make a nice revision and leave a well thought-out answer.